# Solr questions regarding handler resolution and escaping

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I have a couple of questions regarding Solr usage:

1. Certain requests can be sent to different paths (handlers?). For example, the MoreLikeThis component can being sent to either /select or /mlt.

I have found these two links in the Solr wiki:

http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt?q=id:UTF8TEST&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1&mlt.match.include=false

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=apache&mlt=true&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1&fl=id,score

What is the reasoning behind this setup? If I decide to send my MoreLikeThis requests to /mlt does this mean I can not utilize any /select specific calls - if there is even such a thing - such as facets - ? If not, can a /select path can be configured to handle all requests from Spellcheck to Clustering?

1. How do you escape double character special strings (&&, ||) in Lucene?

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping+Special+Characters

Do I escape the first character only (\&&) or do I escape both? And when do I need to escape them? A couple of tests that I performed on the example server provided in the Solr package were inconclusive:

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=manu:%22apple%20%26%26%22%20AND%20manu:%22computer%22

Still returns results,

Answer (score 3):

1) The rationale behind MoreLikeThisHandler is explained in the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis#MoreLikeThisHandler):

> When you specifically want information
>   about similar documents, you can use
>   the MoreLikeThisHandler.
>
> If you want to filter the similar
>   results given by MoreLikeThis you have
>   to use the MoreLikeThisHandler. It
>   will consider the similar document
>   result set as the main one so will
>   apply the specified filters (fq) on
>   it. If you use the
>   MoreLikeThisComponent and apply query
>   filters it will be applyed to the
>   result set returned by the main query
>   (QueryComponent) and not to the one
>   returned by the MoreLikeThisComponent.

2) You need to escape every single character.